# Cómo almacenar varias URL en una variable

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de hacer que en mi sitio solo se pueda acceder a determinadas subpáginas que almaceno en una "whitelist". Lo que tengo hasta el momento es lo siguiente:

```
$errorpage = "/error";
$addtocart = "/module/ps_buybuttonlite/*";
$carritoajax = "/carrito?update=*";
$pagoexitoso1 = "/iniciar-sesion?back=history";
$pagoexitoso2 = "/6-pago-exitoso";

$whitelist=array("/carrito","/pedido",$errorpage,$pagoexitoso1,$pagoexitoso2, $addtocart, $carritoajax);
$currentpage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if ($currentpage == $pagoexitoso1){
    header("Location: $pagoexitoso2");
} elseif (!in_array($currentpage,$whitelist)){
    header("Location: $errorpage");
}
```

Esto funciona parcialmente, ya que, en primer lugar, necesito saber cómo seleccionar todas las URL que contengan $addtocart o $carritoajax, es decir, que entren dentro de la "whitelist" todas las url que contengan "/carrito?update=...", como pueden ver estuve intentando con el * que es la notación que normalmente se utiliza pero en este caso no funciona ¿de qué forma se lo hace?

Además detecto otras anomalías, como por ejemplo, si escribo /carrito1231 (cualquier numero), la pagina accede a la url (cuando no debería), sin embargo cuando se intenta utilizar el /carrito?update la página se bloquea (cuando debería no bloquearse).

Si quieren ver como está funcionando actualmente, lo tengo subido en esta pagina: https://shop.1tiendaonline.com/carrito.

Para añadir un articulo al carrito pueden abrir esta url: https://shop.1tiendaonline.com/module/ps_buybuttonlite/RedirectManager?id_product=21&action=1&id_product_attribute=null
(la url redirecciona a /error pero el artículo se agrega al carro)

Comment: Creo que sería mucho mejor que utilizaras URL's amigables para redirigir las peticiones. Igual esto te sirve: https://www.bonaval.com/kb/sistemas-operativos/linux-sistemas-operativos/ejemplos-de-htaccess-que-todo-webmaster-deberia-conocer

Comment: Trata de no enviar parámetro por get para limpiar las urls.